# How to convert array objects to comma separated objects in php

Tags: php, arrays, object, codeigniter-4

I have a variable, `$my_var` generated within a nested loop, that currently holds two arrays.

`<?php print_r($my_var) ?>` currently returns the below result.

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [name] => Item 1
    [slug] => item-1
)
Array
(
    [id] => 2
    [name] => Item 2
    [slug] => item-2
)
```

However, when I do
`<?php echo json_encode($my_var); ?>`, it returns

```
{"id":"1","name":"Item 1","slug":"item-1"}
{"id":"2","name":"Item 2","slug":"item-2"}
```

One issue from the above data returned is that both objects are not separated by a comma. How can I add **a comma** in between the arrays in `$my_var`

The exact result I am trying to  achieve is like the one below

```
[{"id":"1","name":"Item 1","slug":"item-1"},
{"id":"2","name":"Item 2","slug":"item-2"}]
```

Comment: how is `$my_var` holding those two arrays? inside an array right? then i think it should give you the result you want

Comment: @SumitWadhwa the results in `$my_var` are from multiple nested loops

Comment: Not reproducible http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5d6c83fbf74406b979bf3c5eb9edb8facdc45b93

Comment: @nice_dev thanks so much, you have given me an idea. However, in the two arrays I provided, there is no comma seperating them as I have in my `$my_var`

Comment: @codervine Can you share a `var_export($my_var)`  in your question? When you var_dump();, do you see array or string?

Comment: @nice_dev when I do a var_export, I get `array ( 'id' => '1', 'name' => 'Item 1', 'slug' => 'item-1',) array( 'id' => '2', 'name' => 'Item 2', 'slug' => 'item-2',)`. The both arrays returned are not seperated by a comma. I think that is the only challenge for now

Comment: Ok, what does a var_dump() return you? A string or an array?

Comment: @nice_dev it returns arrays. `C:\wamp\www\dir\app\Controllers\Products.php:33:
array (size=3)
  'id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'name' => string 'Item 1' (length=6)
  'slug' => string 'item-1' (length=6)C:\wamp\www\dir\app\Controllers\Products.php:33:
array (size=3)
  'id' => string '2' (length=1)
  'name' => string 'Item 2' (length=6)
  'slug' => string 'item-2' (length=6)`

Comment: It looks like you are doing two `var_dump()` instead of one! So the problem description does not match that output. You could `json_encode([$myvar1, $myvar2]);` in case of you are having two variables.

Comment: Thanks all, I have been able to solve my challenge